# Understanding RAW image files

Tags: matlab, image-processing, camera, reverse-engineering, tiff

I was wondering if anybody could help me understand RAW files. I know there are a ton of different formats called "RAW," and that it is often manufacturer and even camera specific. I've read that some supposedly contain some kind of "header" that gives info about the file/camera and such.

I'm trying to analyze different RAW outputs from different cameras in Matlab, none of which have much documentation or support as far as I've been able to find over a few days of searching. The popular conversion utilities (Adobe DNG Converter and dcraw) don't recognize these files. I have 5 picture files from each camera, taken with the camera's proprietary software, which should contain 12-bit grayscale data. Endian-ness is not apparent to me (though might be to someone else?). The only other thing I know is what the dimensions of each picture should be.

Basically, is there a way I can reverse-engineer the RAWs I have so that I can understand how to convert them into .tif or something a little more Matlab friendly? I'm pretty new to all of this.

Comment: From which camera / manufacture do the images come? Is it possible to upload an example?

Comment: Sure, @Daniel. Here are sample files from 3 of the cameras, with the files named by the brand of camera:

[link](http://www.mediafire.com/download/mw6tgwpxw4gf405/PointGray.raw)
[link](http://www.mediafire.com/download/x2deku8nidfa2j8/Lumenera.raw)
[link](http://www.mediafire.com/download/eu2lt27z8258d4s/Sentech.bin)

Comment: Oh, and the resolutions for those should be 2704x3376, 1088x2048, and 1236x1624 respectively.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a note - the image sizes you have suggest to me that your images may be stored as 16 bit (possibly with only 12 of those being used in practice).

You really need to contact the manufacturers to be sure.  However, if you have the size and know the precision you can use `fread` and experiment with endianness and direction of dimensions.

So for your Lumenera example, the exact number of bytes is 4,456,448.  This suggests the size is right and the bitdepth is 16: width * height * bitdepth / 8.  The only question then was which way the size went (1088x2048 or 2048x1088) and endianness.  The following looks like a reasonable image to me (not entirely sure what of...)

```
fid = fopen('Lumenera.raw');
A = fread(fid,[2048 1088],'uint16','l');
fclose(fid);
```

[image]

If there is a header and you have some idea of the size of it you can either read that in with `fread` first or `fseek` to the start of the image data if you don't need the contents.

Comment: Thanks for the example, this is definitely helpful and I'll be trying it out a bit here soon.

It's also been suggested to me that I take an image of something more easily recognizable than a laser pointer light when trying to get this all figured out, so there's that. :)

Comment: Just wanted to come back and say thanks again. This is working wonderfully with some trial and error.

Answer (score 0):

I would start wit reading DC RAW files:

http://www.cybercom.net/~dcoffin/dcraw/

Then I would use this MATLAB scripts:
https://plus.google.com/u/0/105777071372887161480/posts/TkdqRq1acuF

Enjoy...

Comment: Did you see how I mentioned that I've tried dcraw and Adobe DNG Converter with no success?

I did find that pdf to be useful in understanding a bit, but it skips the very step that I am confused about by utilizing dcraw or Adobe.

Comment: Look at my second link. This will give you the bridge between the file and MATLAB. It will be easy.

Comment: I did, that's the pdf I'm referring to. What is the bridge you are referring to? As far as I can see the very first step it tells you to take is to use dcraw or Adobe. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can remember camera vendors often supply [WIC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Imaging_Component) codecs for reading their RAWs ([sample](http://software.canon-europe.com/software/0039964.asp)).  You can try this way, especially if you don’t need support for all RAW formats.

I’m not proficient in MATLAB but I’m sure there must be a way to use WIC directly or maybe through 3-rd party tool or SDK.